# GSON - Exclude Object based on Value of Field

Tags: gson

I have some JSON, which contains a key named "type". This key can have the value `include` or `exclude`.  I want to configure Gson to not deserialize the Json, and create an object when the key value is `exclude`.

I realize I can write a custom deserializer, check for the appropriate, and create the object or not.  However, I was not sure if there was another way using some type of exclusion strategy.

The example I outlined is over-simplified.  My real JSON contains many more fields.

```
// Deserialize me
{     
   "type" : "include"
}

// Skip over me, and do not deserialize
{
   "type" : "exclude"
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find any option?

Comment: Did you able to get the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `ExclusionStrategy` can help here. It works with classes rather than instances and at the time instances get processed there's just a result of its evaluation present (in case you want to have a look at the code, see `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.BoundField`).

Answer (score 0):

This might help you...

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jsonObj = gson.fromJson (jsonStr, JsonElement.class).getAsJsonObject();

// Just read the required field
if(jsonObj.get("type").getAsString().equals("include")) {
    // Continue parsing/deserializing other details
} else {
    // Skip
}
```

You can refer [this](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) for Gson API documentation